# RabbitMQ - Client not Receiving

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, messaging, windows-server-2008-r2

I have successfully installed RabbitMQ on my desktop PC and have a small console app to publish messages and another to receive them.  This all works fine.

Now I have installed RabbitMQ on my application server.  Using the management console, I can see the following:

- Exchange is created (topic mode, Auto Delete = false
- No bindings exist on the exchange (they do running on desktop)
- Client does not receive message
- Neither publisher nor subscriber raise any exceptions

I have opened ports 5672 (RabbitMQ) and 15672 (management console) on our firewall and can successfully telnet from my desktop to the server on these ports.  Additionally the management console is working fine.

### Version Details

- RabbitMQ: 3.0.1
- App Server: WIndows 2008 Server R2 Standard
- Client: .Net 4.0
- Client Lib: RabbitMQ.Client (version 3.0.1.0)

Please ask if you need more detail to help - happy to provide.

Thanks,

Graeme

Comment: If no bindings exist between the exchange and the queue you are consuming from, then there will be no messages for the client to consume. You'll need to create a binding between the exchange and the queue that the client is consuming from.

Comment: It took a while to identify, but I got there. To resolve this I did the following: Amend service to run under service account; copy the .erlang.cookies file to the service account's directory.